# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected {

Tags: php

Tenho um ficheiro PHP para verificar se **SESSION** está definida:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']){
   echo "<script>document.location.href='../areaprivada.html';</script>";
   }
 else{
    echo "<script>document.location.href='login.php';</script>";*/
}
?>
```

Mas quando corro dá esse erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercicios\saber2\php\session.php on line 4
```

PS: Linha 4 é a que fecha o `if`.

Comment: remova os caracteres `*/` após o comando do `else` provavelmente corrigirá o problema..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faltou fechar os Parênteses **()** e retirar a tag ***/** de fechamento de comentários

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   echo "<script>document.location.href='../areaprivada.html';</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>document.location.href='login.php';</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Já tens a resposta ao teu problema, mas dado ninguém ter explicado como deve ser lido o erro, fica aqui a minha contribuição para que no futuro consigas entender o que o PHP te está a dizer:</sup>

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercicios\saber2\php\session.php on line 4

O erro divide-se em 3 porções:

- **Tipo de erro:**

  Obtiveste um `Parse error`, da família `E_PARSE` que são basicamente erros que vão impedir que a execução continue.
- **Erro:**

  Obtiveste `syntax error` que indica que alguma coisa está mal com o código PHP cujo interpretador não consegue entender.
- **Descrição:**

  A descrição do teu erro identifica o problema, a linha e o ficheiro onde o erro está localizado.

  No teu caso, `unexpected '{'` na linha `4` do ficheiro `C:\xampp\htdocs\exercicios\saber2\php\session.php`, ou seja, foi encontrado um `{` na linha 4 do referido ficheiro, quando era esperada outra coisa.

Uma vez que o erro aponta para um caractere inesperado, o problema real está antes do mesmo:

```
#01 <?php
#02
#03 session_start();
#04 if(isset($_SESSION['user']){
#05   echo "<script>document.location.href='../areaprivada.html';</script>";
#06   }
#07 else{
#08    echo "<script>document.location.href='login.php';</script>";*/
#09 }
#10 ?>
```

E assim, na tua linha #4, antes do `{` deveria estar outra coisa qualquer. Analisando do início da linha até ao `{` acabamos por nos aperceber que falta fechar o parênteses da condição do `if` com um `)`.

---

Mais sobre os erros e seus tipos:

- [php.net - PHP Error Type](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)
- [careerride.com - PHP Error Type](http://www.careerride.com/PHP-types-errors.aspx)

Comment: Muito boa a tua resposta! Devia haver mais pessoas a dar respostas assim. Pois qualquer pessoa fica a entender o que estava mal. Fico grato pelo facto de dispensar-se tempo para elaborar uma resposta com cabeça, tronco e membros para um melhor entender da situação.

Comment: @BrunoGibellino não precisa fazer nada, mas se achar que deve, é possível trocar a aceitação de resposta por outra que você acha que foi melhor. Sabia disto? O critério de escolha é seu. Eu sempre escolho a melhor resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Deveria ficar desta forma fechando a chave do `else` e o parentese do `if`:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   echo "<script>document.location.href='../areaprivada.html';</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>document.location.href='login.php';</script>";
}
?>
```